# read the html url and parse in php

Tags: php, html, json, html-parsing

I have html code as follows:

```
<html>
......
<div.....>

<div..>
    <ul class="class1">
        <li><div class="class2"><a href="link1">text1</a>...</div><li>
        <li><div class="class2"><a href="link2">text2</a>...</div><li>
        <li><div class="class2"><a href="link3">text3</a>...</div><li><li>
        <div class="class2"><a href="link4">text4</a>...</div><li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="n">
    <a href="nextlink">Next Page »</a>
</div>
</div>
.....
</html>
```

I need to generate a json from this `html()`.

```
{"headings":[{"name":"text1","value":"link1"},{"name":"text2","value":"link2"},
{"name":"text3","value":"link3"}{"name":"text4","value":"link4"}],"nextpage":"nextlink"}
```

Comment: You are better off producing the JSON from the HTMLs data source.

Comment: @Flosculus: i am reading data from a 3rd party webpage.. i need to parse the data of class "classx" from the html and need to create an array

Comment: Read up on PHP DOM http://de1.php.net/manual/de/book.dom.php

Comment: Or just read the SO Answer to your actual Question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php?rq=1